# nodejs is installed in wsl ubuntu but 'node--version' shows 'No such file or directory'

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, npm, windows-subsystem-for-linux, nvm

Installed Nodejs using brew commands, which installed the node, but node commands are not running. The result is always:
'node: error while loading shared libraries: libicui18n.so.73: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory'.

```
pradhyumn_32@HPVictus:~/ic-projects/hello$ nvm --version
0.39.7
pradhyumn_32@HPVictus:~/ic-projects/hello$ nvm install node
v21.7.1 is already installed.
Now using node v21.7.1
pradhyumn_32@HPVictus:~/ic-projects/hello$ node --version
node: error while loading shared libraries: libicui18n.so.73: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
pradhyumn_32@HPVictus:~/ic-projects/hello$ node
node: error while loading shared libraries: libicui18n.so.73: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
pradhyumn_32@HPVictus:~/ic-projects/hello$ npm
node: error while loading shared libraries: libicui18n.so.73: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I tried removing and reinstalling but it didn't work. I searched all over but couldn't find any solution. I also tried to find the libicui18n.so.73 using 'find / ' but still didn't find the library

Comment: I'm confused. How did you install? brew or nvm?

Comment: possible cross site duplicate of https://askubuntu.com/questions/1351096/error-while-loading-shared-libraries-libicui18n-so-66

Comment: first by brew and then nvm

Comment: @Omkar76 shows error: E: 'Unable to locate package libicu73'